# Receiving error "ID3037: The specified request failed adfs" when requesting token from adfs server

Tags: c#, wcf, adfs2.0

Below is the code I'm using to request "Symmetric" token type from Adfs and I receive the error as mentioned in the title.

A quick google search points out that, it is because of the absence of token signing certificate but I do have it defined in the Adfs.

Do I need to explicitly assign it to "Relying party" or having it in ADFS 2.0 works? 
Please can anybody point me to right direction or have somebody knows step to associate token signing certificate to relying party if it is required?

```
WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;


System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannelFactory(
            binding, new EndpointAddress(userNameMixedRequest.GetUserNameMixedUrl));

factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\username"
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password"

System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.RequestSecurityToken request = new System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.RequestSecurityToken
{
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(userNameMixedRequest.ClientUri),
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric
};

System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
channel.Issue(request)
```